# Is there a way to withdraw a specific invite on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I have about 2000 sent invites pending accept from people on LinkedIn and I wanted to withdraw an invite which I sent to a specific person.

So looking for that specific invite is like looking for a needle in a haystack with no search feature offered by LinkedIn.

When I look at the Sent invites page, there are about 20 pages I have to browse through to find the specific person I want to withdraw the invite from. And that's my problem.

Is there a front end hack to show all invites on a single page for example so that I can search for the name in the browser?

I already use LinkedIn helper but the tool only allows you bulk remove all invites setting a specific number for the ones to keep. so that's not ideal.

This is quite frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile there is no script for that you can open each of 20 pages in a new tab and the use the common <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in the browser and search for the name of that person you want to find.

The only challenge is that on each of the pages you would need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and then retype the name of the person. This is the closest to your answer for now until there is a new support from LinkedIn for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your all sent invitations at one page in sent section in [invitation manager](https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invitation-manager/sent/).

- Login to your LinkedIn profile
- Click on My **Network tab** (Next to Home tab)
- Click on **Manage All** (it will redirect you to Manage invitations page)
- Click on **Sent**

Here it will list all the connections whom you have sent invite. There is `Withdraw` button next to each connection. Now scroll down and find out that specific connection and click on Withdraw, it will Withdraw the invite for that connection.

Comment: Thanks @serenesat. I am already aware of all these steps. When are you looking at the Sent invites, there are about 20 pages you have to browse through to find the specific person you want to withdraw the invite from. And that's my problem.

Comment: There is no other official way to withdraw the invite. Atleast I didn't find. May be if anyone have any script can help.

Comment: Yep, that's what I am hoping for.